# Read whole text by delimiter not newline

Tags: bash

I need to read the text file in bash by specified delimiter ('\n\n' - double newline) in whole text (not only in the single line). 
E.g:

```
aaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaa

bbbbbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbbbb
```

should be read as above, not like that:

```
aaaaaaaaaa

aaaaaaaaaaa

bbbbbbbbbbb

bbbbbbbbb

bbbbbbbbbb
```

I tried with -d $'\n\n' (does it support just one character?) flag etc. but with no success.

Gonna complete it later

Comment: I recommend you review [how to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then update your question accordingly; in particular, provide the complete command(s) you've attempted; also, some idea of what you plan on doing with the data (store in variable? print to stdout? parse? store in array?) once you've (successfully) read it from the file would also help

Comment: Your question is unclear. markp put it nicely, you need to provide a better example of what the desired behavior is and provide *precisely* what it is you want to do, including the commands you want and how you want the output stored. You have also not provided an example of what the original text file looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use perl

```
perl -00 -ne 'do_something_with($_)' file
```

But if you need to use bash try this (untested)

```
paragraph=""
while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ -z $line ]]; then            # an empty line
        if [[ -n $paragraph ]]; then   # allow for consecutive empty lines
            do_something_with "$paragraph"
        fi
        paragraph=""
    else
        paragraph+="$line"
    fi
done < file
```

Note that a line containing whitespace will **not** register as empty

Comment: Hi, I did something similar. Thank you.